# How to get table from XML on the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following xml

```
set @Informe  = '<Table>
<Row>
<Cell>Data1.1</Cell>
<Cell>Data1.2</Cell>
<Cell>Data1.3</Cell>
<Cell>Data1.4</Cell>
<Cell>Data1..n</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell>Data2.1</Cell>
<Cell>Data2.2</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell>Data3.1</Cell>
<Cell>Data3.2</Cell>
</Row>
</Table>'
```

I would like to get the table following  as the result of my query

```
Cell       
-----------
Data1.1
Data1.2
Data1.3
Data1.4
Data1..n
```

Just want to get the data from the first "Row".

Can sombody help with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Cells.value('.', 'varchar(25)')
FROM 
    @Informe.nodes('/Table/Row[1]/Cell') AS XTbl(Cells)
```